# Mod_rewrite: hide query string from users with sub domain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, query-string

I am trying to do something very simple yet still confusing.
I have a link 
`http://sub.example.com/folder/?qvar=value`
I want this to be accessible via:
`http://sub.example.com/folder/value`

Very simple yet I cannot figure this out.
I have tried the following to no avail:

```
#RewriteEngine On
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ?qvar=$1 [L, QSA]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /folder/index.php?qvar=$1 [L,QSA]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?qvar=$1 [L,QSA]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /folder/?qvar=$1 [L,QSA]
#RewriteRule ([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?qvar=$1 [L,QSA]

#RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} qvar=(.*)
#RewriteRule index.php  %1 [L]
```

Some of these give me a 500 internal server error.
Others redirect me to /sub/sub/folder/.

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -Multiviews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /folder/\?qvar=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /folder/%1? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^folder/(.*)$ /folder/?qvar=$1 [L,QSA]
```

These rules need to be in the htaccess file in your document root