# HTAccess Redirect Rule Needed

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm looking to rewrite my url's but I can't seem to get the code right

I need to have:

```
mydomain.com/dj
```

become:

```
 mydomain.com/services.php?q=dj
```

but I still want it to show up as

```
 mydomain.com/dj
```

this will be the case for dj, photo, video, etc

Any help would be great!

Stop downvoting me! I have searched all over and not found how to do this

I know how to do:

```
Redirect /page.php?id=3  http://mydomain.site/page/3
```

but I need it to go the other way around

Comment: Post what you've tried!

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and follow the steps shown there, including sharing relevant code as well as signs of research and effort on your part BEFORE creating new topic here. And given the THOUSANDS of htaccess posts and tutorials, it is doubly important that you need to research and trial yourself first

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=htaccess

Comment: I was following along this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20295336/mod-rewrite-hide-query-string-from-users-with-sub-domain but wasn't able to figure out how to rewrite it for my need

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following Rule in your Root/.htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /services.php?q=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

This will rewrite "example.com/foo" to "example.com/service.php?q=foo".

Comment: Thanks! How do I choose what endings it does this for? There are only a few (site.com/dj, site.com/video, and site.com/photo)